# datepicker no past dates

Tags: javascript, datepicker

i need guide on how to apply this restriction for back dates for the date picker as i am new to this javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/datepickr.min.js"></script>

<input class="" type="Text" size="30" name="Date" id="Date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        new datepickr('Date', 
        {
            'dateFormat': 'Y-m-d'
        }

        );
    </script>
```

i do saw some people post about solution like this code, but i don't know how to apply in my code

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});});
```

i have tried this as well, still not working, and it is more worst as the date picker can't be show

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='datepicker'></input>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#date").datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     yearRange: "-35:+0",
     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
     minDate:mdate() });


 function mdate(){
         var str = "-0Y";
         return str; }
         </script>
```

Comment: Are you using JQuery?

Comment: can you give me sample for this jquery? please help out, my code for this date picker thing is just like posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look at this. In it I have used JQuery UI 1.9.2

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <input id="datepicker" type="text" />

<script>
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         minDate: 0
  });
</script>
```

I am setting minDate on load. Use this code and this will work for you. Click Run Code Snippet code if you want to see the code in action.

```js
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
             minDate: 0
    });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" type="text" />
```

Comment: how am i going to put this code in my project? please give me some guide? i need something like my code to understand how this jquery things work.

Comment: Download Jquey UI 1.9. 2 from http://jqueryui.com/download/all/ and refer same in your project and put above code in scipt tag as you have written for new datePicker.

Comment: i have edited my code but still not working...the datepicker can't be display

Comment: Updated code with very simple code also added code snippet. This will work for you.

Comment: thank you so much... this is bothering me for hours.. omg.. thank you once again..